# What are the reasons/scenarios for properties like DisplayMemberPath to be dependency properties?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, properties, dependency-properties

Could anyone explain the reasoning behind making say ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath a dependency property and not just a regular CLR property?

Are there any real life scenarios when such properties are used in data binding scenarios, styles, or other dependency property related situations.

Thanks.

**Update:**

The reason for this question are statements like

> Making your property a dependency
>   property is not always necessary or
>   appropriate and will depend on your
>   needs. Sometimes, the typical
>   technique of backing your property
>   with a private field is adequate.

in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933(VS.95).aspx) which kind of make control developers question declarations of dependency properties which have no clearly identifiable benefits of being a dependency property.with a private field is adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consistency**: As a developer you can't assume that no one out there would require a particular feature(in a particular case). When I develop any custom control I make sure to make all public properties DP's as you never know someone using that control/property may have a requirement to bind it or use it in style etc. **So it is better to be consistent; as, if some of controls properties support Binding, styling etc. I expect other properties to support them too.**

I have faced this issue a lot with 3'rd party controls like Sync-fusion; On numerous occasions we had raised tickets asking for Binding support for various control properties. As mentioned in this question:

[Why do so many wpf controls implement CLR properties instead of dependency properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572101/why-do-so-many-wpf-controls-implement-clr-properties-instead-of-dependency-proper)

There can be a particular reason for having this property as DP but in general I haven't come across any property(WPF Controls) which is not a DP; and thats really useful, you can design UI(using Binding, styling etc.) without going and checking each and every property of all controls.

Comment: Examples of properties which are not DP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767867/all-wpf-control-properties-are-dependency-properties-true-or-false/3768312#3768312

Comment: The reason for this question are statements like "Making your property a dependency property is not always necessary or appropriate and will depend on your needs. Sometimes, the typical technique of backing your property with a private field is adequate." in MSDN documentation. Things like this make me question non-obvious dependency property declarations.

Comment: @Alan - Yup, I totally agree with you. its confusing, on what basis you can decide this? If you look at the scenarios/cases in which you should use DP here -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=VS.90).aspx#backing_with_dp it becomes really tough to decide this.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMemberPath` is probably rarely defined with a binding, but I can think of scenarios where it would be useful...

For instance, if you want to create a `DataGrid` where you dynamically control the columns, you might need to bind `DisplayMemberPath` to some property of your ViewModel.

You could also set it in a style or template trigger to display one member or another depending on some condition.