# All WPF control properties are dependency properties. True or False?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

While answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767410/what-are-the-reasons-scenarios-for-properties-like-displaymemberpath-to-be-depend/3767801#3767801) question I noticed that I have never come across any property which is not a dependency property (WPF Controls, no 3rd party controls). Although, when I started with WPF I remember reading somewhere that "more then 90% of properties of WPF controls are dependency properties".

Can anyone give examples/links of CLR properties in WPF controls and why it's so?

**Update:**

Came across this lecture:
http://www.miszalok.de/Lectures/L17_WPF/C4_DependencyProperties/DependencyProperties.pdf

Which says:

Label has 18 traditional and 71 dependency properties.

Button has 18 traditional and 78 dependency properties.

Comment: GridLength is an example of one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PasswordBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx) property [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password.aspx) is not implemented as dependency property to not allow data binding, which would be a security risk otherwise. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7ca97b60-2d8e-4a27-8c5b-b8d5d7370a5e/) for details.

Comment: Ohh yes, I remember one of my colleague facing this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Panel.Children` or `FrameworkElement.Resources` are not dependency properties

Answer (score 1):

Also the `CommandParameters` pre WPF 4 was CLR properties!

Taken from MSDN:

> Bind to `commands` on `InputBinding`.
>   You can bind the Command property of an `InputBinding` class to an instance that is defined in code. The following properties are dependency properties, so that they can be targets of bindings:
>
> - InputBinding.Command
> - InputBinding.CommandParameter
> - InputBinding.CommandTarget
> - KeyBinding.Key
> - KeyBinding.Modifiers
> - MouseBinding.MouseAction

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx

Comment: That doesn't seem right since I usually bind values to them in 3.5sp1

Comment: You can bind to clr properties, with one caveat: it will be OneTime binding.